# jquery cross domain authentication

Tags: jquery, http, authentication, cross-domain, jetty

I configures my Jetty server to allow cross domain http requests (allowedOrigins = *) and also to allow cross domain authentication (allowCredentials=true) using its CrossOriginFilter.
Cross domain http requests without authentication requirement work ok. Now when it comes to http calls that require authentication It doesn't work out using JQuery. I use the following code and followed this example: http://www.aswinanand.com/2009/01/http-basic-authentication-using-ajax/

```
function login(username, password) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    url: url,
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        var base64 = Base64.encode(username + ":" + password);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + base64);
        xhr.withCredentials = true;
    },
    error: function(data){
        alert("error");
    },
    success: function(data){
        alert("success"); 
    }
});
```

In HTTPFox i see the following request to the server:

```
OPTIONS /login HTTP/1.1
...
Access-Control-Request-Method   GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers  authorization,content-type
```

The server responds with a

```
HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
...
Allow   OPTIONS,GET,HEAD
```

I also used the options below, which doesnt make a difference.

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    username: username,
    password: password,
    ...
}
```

The error function always fires.
Anybody an idea what the problem could be?

Comment: Do you see this in your response header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*`?  Great question by the way! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you could show any stacktraces related to the issue as well.

Comment: ok, please check to see if that header is included in your response. If not, then it's possible the security is overriding the response headers. Need to see more logs to debug further. Good luck! :)

Comment: @jmort253: no i dont see this header in the response from the server.
The security of jetty? What kind of logs or stacktraces can I provide?

Comment: This would be at the framework or server level. The server typically logs things at a much lower level than your app does, so you'd need to modify logging.properties (or whatever logger you use) and set it to log at DEBUG or ALL so you can see what the server and framework are doing under the hood. You're looking for any instance of the headers being set without the Access-origin header

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the default allowed headers are

> X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,Origin

I had to add the headers

> authorization,content-type

Found this via the log file

> DEBUG [2012-05-27 17:04:02,468] org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter: Headers [authorization,content-type] are not among allowed headers [X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Origin]

Thanks for all the hints!

Answer (score 3):

The response headers that you set in your application -- when security is not enabled 00 works just fine, as you've attested to. However, when security is enabled, your cross-domain requests fail.

This is likely due to the additional Filter and additional response headers that are set by the security filter in order to generate a response.

To solve this problem, the high level solution is that you must set *your* response headers prior to the time that the security Filter sets its response headers and/or commits them to the client.

You're also using Jetty; therefore, you can use the [Jetty Cross Origin Filter](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Feature/Cross_Origin_Filter) to ensure that the response headers are set in the Filter chain, in the order that they need to be set:

Here is a list of parameters that you can pass into the Filter configuration in web.xml:

> - allowedOrigins, a comma separated list of origins that are allowed to access the resources. Default value is *, meaning all origins
> - allowedMethods, a comma separated list of HTTP methods that are allowed to be used when accessing the resources. Default value is GET,POST
> - allowedHeaders, a comma separated list of HTTP headers that are allowed to be specified when accessing the resources. Default value is X-Requested-With
> - preflightMaxAge, the number of seconds that preflight requests can be cached by the client. Default value is 1800 seconds, or 30 minutes
> - allowCredentials, a boolean indicating if the resource allows requests with credentials. Default value is false

By default, the Allowed Origins response header is set to `*`, which implies that by default, any request can be made from any domain. You'll need to be sure to modify this to allow only domains that you intend to whitelist, assuming you don't want every request from all domains to be valid:

**web.xml entry for the Filter:**

```
<web-app ...>
    ...
    <filter>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    ...
</web-app>
```

Here is a list of additional resources that you may find helpful in solving this particular problem:

- [Jetty Cross Origin Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8303162/552792)
- [Access Control Allow Origin not allowed by](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9327218/552792)
- [Java EE 5 Tutorial - Filtering Requests and Responses](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnagb.html)
- [HttpServletResponseWrapper javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponseWrapper.html) - You may need this in case you need to override the HttpServletResponse object.
- [Setting Authentication Header in Servlet via Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4899613/552792)
- [Differences between ServletResponse and HttpServletResponseWrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7023374/552792)
- [How to add response headers based on Content-type; getting Content-type before the response is committed](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2563344/552792)

Answer (score 0):

For SOAP stuff, the allowed headers should also include messagetype,soapaction

Beware that no wildcard is allowed to configure the allowed headers...