# Ajax crossdomain request with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I trying to make a call to an external domain using $.ajax() and it WORKS, the server receives the call, but the response in firebug errors out in jquery.js line 7760. I've been beating my head at this all day and don't feel like I've made it much further.

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://admin:asdfg@149.50.143.241:81/stream.jpg",
            //data: {},
            //async: true,
            //contentType: "application/jsonp; charset=utf-8",
            //headers: {
            //    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5',
            //    'Accept': '*/*',
            //    'Authorization': 'Basic ' + auth
            //},
            //timeout: 500,
            dataType: "jsonp",
            //crossDomain: true,
            beforeSend: function (req) {
                req.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.46 Safari/536.5');
                req.setRequestHeader('Accept', '*/*');
                req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' + auth);
            },
            success: function (data) {
                alert("Success");
            }
        });
```

Comment: `jsonp` does not support `success`

Comment: refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/10827375/946170

Comment: @diEcho, can you please send a link to back your information

Comment: read about jsonp in [`jquery ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: @diEcho, I have read it. It say that `error` handler is not called. But nothing such mentioned for `success` callback. Please recheck and post.

Answer (score 0):

A jsonp response must be wrapped inside a javascript method call. (Callback method).

Assuming the response is an image. It looks unlikely that jquery will be able to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you can use the ajax call to call an image.

When you use jsonp the beforeSend at ajax call is ignored.

Maybe you have to make your server aware and responsive to CORS.

Something like this:

```
    protected override void OnStartProcessingRequest(ProcessRequestArgs args)
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;    // set cache policy to this page 

        context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (context.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
            context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With, Accept");
            context.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3628800");
            context.Response.AddHeader("type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
            context.Response.End();
        }
    }
```

and use the XDomainRequest and XMLHttpResquest to make the call at client side.

take a look here: http://andre-pedroso.blogspot.pt/2011/02/javascript-consume-service-with-cross.html

Cheers